# Long title of table caption in list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, tocloft

Is there a way of the second line of the title of the table be right below the start of the first line? Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left = 3cm,right = 2cm,top = 3cm,bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand*{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize\MakeUppercase{Lista de Tabelas}\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Tabela }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ ---}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \pagebreak
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Some naughty table that has a long title just to show my point that a longe title which takes two lines doesn't continue just below the start of the first line}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c}
            \hline 
            A & B \\ 
            \hline 
            C & D \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

What I have and what I wish I had:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\cfttabfont` is supposed to be some font changing command and it is *not* for adding stuff before the number. If you want to add stuff before the number, use `\cfttabpresnum` instead. Also, the format `Tabela <num> ---` needs more `numwidth`, so let’s set both `\cfttabindent` and `\cfttabnumwidth` via a single call to `\cftsetindents`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left = 3cm,right = 2cm,top = 3cm,bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand*{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize\MakeUppercase{Lista de Tabelas}\hfill}
% Not this:
%\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Tabela }
% But this:
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tabela~}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ ---}
%\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
% Both \cfttabindent and \cfttabnumwidth need to be changed
\cftsetindents{table}{0pt}{5.5em}% Adjust 5.5em if necessary

\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \pagebreak
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Some naughty table that has a long title just to show my point that a longe title which takes two lines doesn't continue just below the start of the first line}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c}
            \hline 
            A & B \\ 
            \hline 
            C & D \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: LoT]

Comment: It worked really well, thank you. But the line between the first table and the second is greater than the others. Do you know why?

Comment: @Levy What do you mean? Which line specifically?

Comment: When I add more entries the space between the first entry is bigger than the others. See here: https://imgur.com/AXWtAPB

Comment: @Levy Using the MWE you provided, I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D88cy.png. So I think there must be something else in your document that is causing this new problem.

Comment: That's odd. I'll search what may be conflicting.

Comment: @Levy Could it be the "chapterlistsgap" (usually 10pt) which is inserted at every usage of `\chapter` into the List of Figures and List of Tables? What document class are you using?

Comment: I'm using report. But I don't know if it's the space of 10pt you said. I still couldn't find any conflict.

Comment: @Levy I think Axel is right. Is your Figure 1 in one chapter, while the other three figures are in a different chapter? If they are in two different chapters, a “chapter separation” is inserted (and is usually desired).

Comment: Yes! Indeed they are. Do you know how to eliminate this space?